# How to Divide a iPhone UIWebView Content into Multiple Pages

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to Divide a UIWebView contents such a way that user need not scroll down to see the more contents of web view. When user presses some button in view the remaining contents will be shown in the next view and in next view same functionality should follow. Is there any way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: have you reached what you wanted? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView has UIScrollView scrollView property which can be sent scrollRectToVisible:animated:... if you have controll over HTML loaded, might be better to change viewport trough JS..

Answer (score 0):

A better approach will be to add a UITabbar and add UIBarButtonItems on it, at the bottom of UIWebview..

Further each of the barbuttons can be assigned UIWebView inbuilt events ..

> goBack,goForward,stopReloading,Refresh.

just by right  clicking the webView and assigning any corresponding action mentioned above to the UIBarButtonItems present on the TabBar below

Comment: Thats not what I wanted to do. I want to Divide the contents of UIWebViewContents. If the Contents Of WebView is Google Search results I want Adjust it to multiple Views such a way that user need not scroll down to see more contents. If he press next button the more contents should be displayed..